# Create an use readonly in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I want to ask you how to create an user with read permissions only in SQL server 2014. In previous versions there was a user group called like db_readonly, but not in the last version.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally i solve the issue with the following article.

http://akawn.com/blog/2014/07/granting-read-only-access-to-multiple-databases-in-sql-server-2014/

You must be sure that the default permisions (i mean in the restrictive way) are set in public security group, if not, the limit of permission is useless.

Regards